# How can I test for -- void add(Object val) and Object at(int index) using jUnit testing(java)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, testng

I am new to jUnit testing and I have the below code that requires being tested. I am trying to test for add(Object val) and Object at(int index).
How do I go about those?

```
public class ResizingArray
{
   // declare the one stack.
   private Object[] Stack;     
   private int length; //array length       
   private int n; //number of elements

   public ResizingArray(int n) //Constructor
   {
      //Create a new stack with n elements of ints.
      Stack = new Object[n];

      length = 0;       //no items yet      
   }

       //return numbers of elements in stack.
   public int length()
   {
      return length;
   }

       //Return the object at the indicated index of the array.
   public Object at(int index)
   {
      if(index < length)
      {
         return Stack[index];
      }
      else
      {
         throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
      }
   }

       //add an object at the next available index 
   public void add(Object val)
   {
      //increment length
      if(length() < Stack.length)
      {
         length++;
      }
   }

jUnit Test //This is the jUnit testing

import org.junit.Assert;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ResizingArrayTest 
{
   protected ResizingArray newStack2;   

    public ResizingArrayTest()
    {      
    }

   atTest
   public void testLength()
   {
         int[] newStack1 = new int[100]; //a new stack with 100 elements
       //use the for loop to inialize 100 elements
      for(int i = 0; i <= newStack1.length; ++i)
      {
         assertEquals((100),newStack1.length); //test for length.
         newStack1.add(i+1);         //test for add
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Was this answer helpful? If yes, May I request to accept the answer that was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

In general, we can use `Mockito` or `PowerMock` libraries to test the void methods. However, the `add()` and `at()` methods can be tested like below:-

Please note that this is just a sample tests. You can extend to cover many scenarios if needed.

**Concept:-**

**add()** - If the `add()` method is executed successfully, then length should be incremented. So assert the length value.

**at()** - If `at()` method is executed successfully, it should return the object. So, assert the object value.

Neither the constructor nor the add() assigns the object value to Stack variable. So, the `at()` always return null if it is not out of index.

```
public class ResizingArrayTest {


@Test
public void addTestString() {
    ResizingArray resizingArray = new ResizingArray(2);

    resizingArray.add(new String("Str1"));
    Assert.isTrue(resizingArray.length() == 1);

    resizingArray.add(new String("Str2"));
    Assert.isTrue(resizingArray.length() == 2);

    //Max only 2 can be added as per the ResizingArray object creation
    resizingArray.add(new String("Str3"));
    Assert.isTrue(resizingArray.length() == 2);

}

@Test
public void addTestDoesnotAddString() {
    ResizingArray resizingArray = new ResizingArray(0);

    //Nothing can be added
    resizingArray.add(new String("Str1"));
    Assert.isTrue(resizingArray.length() == 0);             

}

@Test
public void atTest() {
    ResizingArray resizingArray = new ResizingArray(1);

    resizingArray.add(new String("Str1"));
    Assert.isNull(resizingArray.at(0));


}

@Test(expected = ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
public void atTestThrowException() {
    ResizingArray resizingArray = new ResizingArray(0);

    resizingArray.at(1);


}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first of all i think you should alter a bit the add(Object) method so that you actually add the Object to the array:

```
//add an object at the next available index 
public void add(Object val)
{
  //increment length
  if(length() < Stack.length)
  {
     Stack[length] = val;
     length++;
  }
}
```

Secondly, you should also check when retrieving a value that the passed index is not negative:

```
//Return the object at the indicated index of the array.
public Object at(int index)
{
    if(index >= 0 && index < length)
    {
        return Stack[index];
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
}
```

Then we go to the tests.
The way i test my methods is by trying to create a separate unit test for each of the possible scenarios. Thanks to that your test code gains clarity, will be easier to maintain and conforms to the Single Responsibility Principle.

**So he is the suite of tests that i would run:**

```
import  static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ResizingArrayTest {

    private ResizingArray resizingArray;
    private int defaultArraySize;
    Integer valueToAddOne = Integer.valueOf(1);
    Integer valueToAddTwo = Integer.valueOf(2);
    Integer valueToAddThree = Integer.valueOf(3);

    @Before
    public void init(){
        defaultArraySize = 2;
        resizingArray = new ResizingArray(defaultArraySize);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldAddValueToTheStack() throws Exception{
        // Act
        resizingArray.add(valueToAddOne);

        // Assert
       assertThat("Array Length", resizingArray.length(), equalTo(1));
       assertThat("Top Value",   (Integer)resizingArray.at(resizingArray.length()-1), equalTo(valueToAddOne));

        // Act
       resizingArray.add(valueToAddTwo);

       // Assert
       assertThat("Array Length", resizingArray.length(), equalTo(2));
       assertThat("Top Value", (Integer)resizingArray.at(resizingArray.length()-1), equalTo(valueToAddTwo));
       }

    @Test
    public void shouldNotAddValueToTheStack() throws Exception{
        // Arrange
        resizingArray.add(valueToAddOne);
        resizingArray.add(valueToAddTwo);

        // Act
        resizingArray.add(valueToAddThree);

        // Assert
        assertThat("Top Value", (Integer)   resizingArray.at(resizingArray.length() - 1), equalTo(valueToAddTwo));
}



    @Test(expected = ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
    public void shouldThrowException_WhenRetrievingValueByNegativeIndex()  throws Exception{
        // Act
       resizingArray.at(-1);
    }

   @Test(expected = ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
   public void shouldThrowException_WhenRetrievingValueByIndexGreaterThanStackSize() throws Exception{
       // Act
       resizingArray.at(3);
}

   @Test
   public void shouldRetrieveValueByIndex() throws Exception{
       // Arrange
       resizingArray.add(valueToAddOne);
       resizingArray.add(valueToAddTwo);

       // Act
       Integer firstElement = (Integer) resizingArray.at(0);
       Integer secondElement = (Integer) resizingArray.at(1);

       // Assert
       assertThat("First element", (Integer) resizingArray.at(0), equalTo(firstElement));
       assertThat("Second element", (Integer) resizingArray.at(1), equalTo(secondElement));

   }
```

}

**Few key points:**

- @Before - in this init method i put the basic set-up of the object under test which every test would take as a Prototype.
- Splitting each method into 'Arrange / Act / Assert' ads a lot clarity. In the end every test case has this struture.. so stick to it.
- Don't be afraid of choosing long names for your tests, even with some uncommon characters like '_'. Again this add to the clarity. If some of your tests fail.. you know straight away whats wrong just by looking at the name of test.